# How do I write the lookup_value in vlookup VBA as a range

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm new to VBA - I'm trying to write a Vlookup Function within Excel to refer to the lookup_value as a range of values. I have stored my values in a range called lookup_range, however I get N/A when I output the vlookup value to cells.

I have searched all over the internet, however I'm not seeing any solution to my questions.

```
Sub Vlookup_values()

    Dim Vlkp_cell, n As Double
    Dim Search_range, row_end, col_end As Double

    Sheets("Movement").Activate
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
    Vlkp_cell = ActiveCell.Row

    ReDim Lookup_range(Vlkp_cell) As String
    n = 0
    Range("A1").Select
    For n = 1 To Vlkp_cell
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Lookup_range(n) = ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = Lookup_range(n)
    Next n

    Sheets("Mapping").Activate
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
    row_end = ActiveCell.Row

    Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Select
    col_end = ActiveCell.Column

    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(row_end, col_end)).Name = "Search_range"
    Range("Search_Range").Select

    Sheets("Movement").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    n = 0
    For n = 1 To Vlkp_cell

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Application.VLookup(Lookup_range(n), Search_range, 2, False)

    Next n


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was able to understand what you are trying to achieve from your code, then try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Vlookup_values()

    Dim Vlkp_cell As Long, n As Long
    Dim Search_range As Range, row_end As Long, col_end As Long

    With Sheets("Mapping")
        row_end = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        col_end = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

        Set Search_range = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(row_end, col_end)) ' <-- set the Range for the VLookup
    End With

    With Sheets("Movement")
        Vlkp_cell = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

        For n = 1 To Vlkp_cell
            .Range("A" & n).Offset(0, 9).Value = .Range("A" & n).Value ' <-- not sure why you need the values copied 9 column to the right ?
            .Range("B" & n).Value = Application.VLookup(.Range("A" & n).Value, Search_range, 2, False)
        Next n
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @ifeelcrazy123 have you tested the code in my answer ?

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked!! (Sorry for the late reply). FYI, I needed the values 9 columns to the right as the previous 8 are filled with other data which I will need to compare and submit into a financial system later. Thank you!